# Zip folder from resources into jar

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to zip a folder in my resources folder, then put that zip instead of the folder in the output jar.
Example:

```
resources
|- my-folder
|---- test.txt
```

Output:

```
myjar.jar
|- my-folder.zip
|---- test.txt
```

My current task for zipping:

```
task zipResources(type:Zip) {
    classifier = 'test-zip'
    from projectDir
    sourceSets*.resources.stream()
        .flatMap({ set -> set.files.stream() })
        .filter({ file -> file.getAbsolutePath().contains('resource-pack') })
        .forEach({ file ->
            println file
            include file.getAbsolutePath() 
        })
}
```

That prints the test.txt
I've also tried with

```
from projectDir
include 'src/main/resources/resource-pack'
```

and various other variations, but no luck so far. How the heck do I do this?

Comment: what's the issue? to zip or to jar? any errors?

Comment: No errors, no zip was made in the jar or build folder. Luckily PrasadU had some sample code that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have line up the tasks here - myZip between processResources and jar

sample:

```
processResources {
    exclude 'records-dir/'
}

task myZip(type: Zip) {
    destinationDirectory = file('build/resources/main')
    archiveFileName = 'records-dir.zip'
    from 'src/main/resources/records-dir'
}

myZip.mustRunAfter processResources
jar.dependsOn myZip
```

Comment: I dunno how I never tried that, thanks for the sample!